# Jetty server cannot return json

Tags: java, json, rest, maven, jetty

When I use mvn jetty:run to start my server, it cannot return json format string, it seems to only return raw string or "null" for all objects

My endpoint code, you see there is no difference but to return string in a wrapped object and return as raw string

```
 @Path("/snapsono/")  
 public class RestEndPoint {  
     GeneralServer server = new GeneralImpl();  
     private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("RestEndPoint");  
     @GET
     @Path("/hello")
     @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
     public SnapString sayHello() throws Exception{
        logger.info("reach hello");
        SnapString snapString = new SnapString("hello");
        logger.info("this is: "+snapString.getString());
        return snapString;
     } 

     @GET
     @Path("/helloString")
     @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
     public String sayHelloString() throws Exception{
        return "hello";
     }
   }
```

For the SnapString class, I do add the @XmlRootElement at the class region

```
@XmlRootElement
public class SnapString {
    private String str = "";
    public SnapString(){
    }

    public SnapString(String str){
        this.str = str;
    }

    public String getString(){
        return this.str;
    } 
}
```

but when I run it, I got the following return

```
dilin-mbp:~ dilin$ curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type:  application/json" -X GET http://localhost:9090/snapsono/hello
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Server: Jetty(8.1.16.v20140903)

null

dilin-mbp:~ dilcurl -i -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X GET http://localhost:9090/snapsono/helloString
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Server: Jetty(8.1.16.v20140903)

hello

dilin-mbp:~ dilin$
```

That is, it is ok to return a raw string but cannot return an object in Json format, and when it is wrapped, it is always return null.

Mean while, from the log I can tell that the return object does have value

```
[INFO] Restart completed at Mon Feb 16 21:53:56 PST 2015
Feb 16, 2015 9:54:48 PM snap.sono.demo.rest.RestEndPoint sayHello
INFO: reach hello
Feb 16, 2015 9:54:48 PM snap.sono.demo.rest.RestEndPoint sayHello
INFO: this is: hello
Feb 16, 2015 9:57:45 PM snap.sono.demo.rest.RestEndPoint sayHello
```

Please check my naive implementation for the two Info log

The entire jetty start up message is:

```
dilin-mbp:snapsono dilin$ mvn jetty:run
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-  server:8.1.8.v20121106: Failed to parse plugin descriptor for   org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server:8.1.8.v20121106      (/Users/dilin/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-server/8.1.8.v20121106/jetty-  server-8.1.8.v20121106.jar): No plugin descriptor found at META-     INF/maven/plugin.xml
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Sproject 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server:8.1.8.v20121106: Failed to parse plugin descriptor for org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server:8.1.8.v20121106   (/Users/dilin/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-server/8.1.8.v20121106/jetty-  server-8.1.8.v20121106.jar): No plugin descriptor found at META-  INF/maven/plugin.xml
[INFO]
[INFO] >>> jetty-maven-plugin:8.1.8.v20121106:run (default-cli) > test-compile @ Sproject >>>
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ Sproject ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (MacRoman actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /Users/dilin/Documents/workspace/snapsono/src/main/resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ Sproject ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ Sproject ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (MacRoman actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /Users/dilin/Documents/workspace/snapsono/src/test/resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ Sproject ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] <<< jetty-maven-plugin:8.1.8.v20121106:run (default-cli) < test-compile @ Sproject <<<
[INFO]
[INFO] --- jetty-maven-plugin:8.1.8.v20121106:run (default-cli) @ Sproject ---
[INFO] Configuring Jetty for project: Sproject
[INFO] webAppSourceDirectory not set. Defaulting to /Users/dilin/Documents/workspace/snapsono/src/main/webapp
[INFO] Reload Mechanic: automatic
[INFO] Classes = /Users/dilin/Documents/workspace/snapsono/target/classes
[INFO] Context path = /
[INFO] Tmp directory = /Users/dilin/Documents/workspace/snapsono/target/tmp
[INFO] Web defaults = org/eclipse/jetty/webapp/webdefault.xml
[INFO] Web overrides =  none
[INFO] web.xml file =     file:/Users/dilin/Documents/workspace/snapsono/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml
[INFO] Webapp directory = /Users/dilin/Documents/workspace/snapsono/src/main/webapp
2015-02-16 22:00:01.766:INFO:oejs.Server:jetty-8.1.8.v20121106
2015-02-16 22:00:02.128:INFO:oejpw.PlusConfiguration:No Transaction manager found - if your webapp requires one, please configure one.
Null identity service, trying login service: null
Finding identity service: null
2015-02-16 22:00:03.549:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:started o.m.j.p.JettyWebAppContext{/,file:/Users/dilin/Documents/workspace/snapsono/src/main/webapp/},file:/Users/dilin/Documents/workspace/snapsono/src/main/webapp/
2015-02-16 22:00:03.549:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:started o.m.j.p.JettyWebAppContext{/,file:/Users/dilin/Documents/workspace/snapsono/src/main/webapp/},file:/Users/dilin/Documents/workspace/snapsono/src/main/webapp/
2015-02-16 22:00:03.549:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:started o.m.j.p.JettyWebAppContext{/,file:/Users/dilin/Documents/workspace/snapsono/src/main/webapp/},file:/Users/dilin/Documents/workspace/snapsono/src/main/webapp/
Feb 16, 2015 10:00:03 PM com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig init
INFO: Scanning for root resource and provider classes in the packages:
  snap.sono.demo.rest
Feb 16, 2015 10:00:03 PM com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig logClasses
INFO: Root resource classes found:
  class snap.sono.demo.rest.RestEndPoint
Feb 16, 2015 10:00:03 PM com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig init
INFO: No provider classes found.
  Feb 16, 2015 10:00:03 PM     com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl _initiate
INFO: Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.8 06/24/2011 12:17 PM'
2015-02-16 22:00:04.040:INFO:oejs.AbstractConnector:Started       SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:9090
[INFO] Started Jetty Server
[INFO] Starting scanner at interval of 40 seconds.
```

Comment: I tried the same with jetty 9. It worked. I got {"string":"hello"} for snapsono/hello

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved this issue.

That is, in the class level we need to tag as @XmlRootElement

Then for each return attribute, we need to tag it as @XmlElement, such that the member variables which are tagged can be returned in json format.